# uitextfield is not convertible to uint8

Tags: ios, swift

im trying to get a button to output numbers onto a textfield but i keep getting this error

this is my code, the amountOutput is the one with the error

```
@IBAction func Output(sender: AnyObject) {
    yieldOutput.text = String (format:"%.2f", yield[1] )
    amountOutput.text = Double (typeAmount * (yieldOutput / 100)) + unit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`yieldOutput` in your code isn't a number, it's a text field. That means that to use the value in it, you need to transform it into a number or use a variable that already holds that value. In your case, `yield[1]` is the variable you use to set the value for `yieldOutput`. Just do:

```
amountOutput.text = Double (typeAmount * (yield[1] / 100)) + unit
```